# VBA - I'm trying to save a report as a PDF, but it only opens the report

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

My code is below. It opens the report, but it looks like it stops there. It never reaches the message box. So I'm guessing that it's failing at the export part. But my breakpoints don't trigger when I click my button. So I can't see what's happening.

Any ideas on what's going on?

```
Private Sub Command552_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "report_name", acViewPreview, , "[RowID] = 16094"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, "C:\Users\name\Desktop\test.pdf", True

    DoCmd.Close acReport, "report_name"

    MsgBox ("done")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a problem on the server I'm running this on. It doesn't have the necessary components to support exporting to PDF. When I changed the export format to RTF, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're unsure of where the code is breaking, I'd recommend removing all unnecessary parameters from

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, "C:\Users\name\Desktop\test.pdf", True
```

so you're left with something like this

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport
```

You'll be prompted to put in file name and location, as well as choose file format. See if it saves properly. Then, place the first parameter back on the line of code:

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ""

Repeat the process until the code breaks, and then you've narrowed down where you're crashing.

From there, help could be more easily given.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to open the report from a form and output it.

The form does not know you want to output the report. 
So you either have to add the doCmd.Output... to the code in the report, or you have to set specify object to the doCmd.Output...

You can try:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "report_name", acFormatPDF, _ 
             "C:\Users\name\Desktop\test.pdf", True
```

Comment: I run into the same issue with your example